# How to debug a ReactNative app which is not opening

Tags: react-native

I've been moved to a RN project and I'm new to this. If I create a new app/project is starts perfectly on my phone but this one doesn't. It shows "the app has stopped working".

I tried with a simple `index` removing the rest of the functions but nothing.

How could I see some logs or where could I remove some other configurations/functions?

`index.android.js`:

```
"use strict";

import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./src/index";

AppRegistry.registerComponent("ReactNativeTS", () => App);
```

`/src/index.tsx` (the default one):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: "Press Cmd+R to reload,\n" + "Cmd+D or shake for dev menu",
  android:
    "Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n" +
    "Shake or press menu button for dev menu"
});

interface Props {}
export default class dejavu extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native2rr!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.tsx</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What is the most relevat file to show? Sorry but as I said I'm new with RN. I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

*The app has stopped working* probably means you're running on Android.

If you have Android Studio, you should use [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) to see what the exception is.

You'll see the full stack trace and can go from there.

Comment: I get all the time `WifiPermissionsUtil: Denied: no location permission`. Btw, I use Linux command line

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing some permissions. Try to add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You'll find this file in android/app/src/main.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native log-android` will display some information about these errors